# Ubuntu 19.10 + i3 WM freezing constantly

Tags: graphics, encryption, freeze, 19.10, i3-wm

Update: The few people that responded seem to focus on the graphic card issues, however trying to replicate with heavy GPU load has yielded nothing ,but trying to replicate with loads of FS usage has (seems to be that heavy I/O usage is enough, but heavy FS usage, as in creating loads of nodes, will freeze things even if I/O is waaay under capacity).

Thus I'm currently suspecting that it's an issue related to LUKS and/or the specific ASE instructions of the CPU and/or just the basic limitations of an encrypted file system.

Unless someone has meet similar issue I will probably investigate some more when I have time and post a different Question that focuses more on the fs related issues.

---

I've got a relatively decent new laptop on which I recently installed Ubuntu 19.4 ( and updated to 19.10 ).

Basic hardware & system info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64
Kernel: 5.3.0-26-generic
CPU: Intel i7-8750H (12) @ 4.100GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile 
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 630 
Memory: 15861MiB
```

Nvidia driver info:

```
nvidia_uvm            954368  0
nvidia_drm             49152  7
nvidia_modeset       1114112  7 nvidia_drm
nvidia              20406272  296 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        184320  2 nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   491520  11 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
ipmi_msghandler       102400  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
i2c_nvidia_gpu         16384  0

ii  libnvidia-cfg1-440:amd64         440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-440             440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-440:amd64      440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-440:i386       440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-440:amd64       440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-440:i386        440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-440:amd64       440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-440:i386        440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-440:amd64         440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386          440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-440:amd64           440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-440:i386            440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-440:amd64         440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386          440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-440         440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-440                  440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-440                440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-440         440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-440         440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                     0.8.13                    all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                  435.21-0ubuntu2           amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-440                 440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440    440.44-0ubuntu0~0.19.10.1 amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Some more relevant info might be the fact that I've opted for the encrypted file system option on install (not sure what the underlying encryption is) and that I'm using i3 windows manager (installed via apt-get, using it by selecting it in the login screen)

The system seem to freeze randomly despite the fact that CPU and Memory usage are very low (e.g. all CPUs but one < 5%, memory < 20% utilization).

I have absolutely not idea why. The freezes sometimes last 10+ minutes and force me to reboot, otherwise it's only a few seconds.

It seems that they usually happen when I combine browser usage (especially video streaming) with an i/o intensive process such as downloading a file or un-taring a very large archive with loads of sub-dirs inside of it.

It's rather hard to describe for how long and often this happen, since again, I can't seem to trace it back to any resource usage issue that I can log or to any errors in `journalctl`.

As it stands I'm considering three options:

- Something wrong with my gpu drivers (though I did install the latest proprietary drivers)
- Encrypted FS that Ubuntu uses by default is very very bad under moderate i/o and somehow causes freezes (doubt it because I have a pretty good NVME-SSD and my processor supports ASE, but not VAES though)
- I3 setup that Ubuntu did by default when I installed the package is severely buggy in some way (doubt it though, because I've installed it from scratch several time and I couldn't think of anything that could go this horribly wrong)

After a day of debugging I'm close to giving up, since the issue is so hard to trace, as there's no noticeable "problem" outside of the fact that the screen itself freezes in weird ways at unpredictable times.

However, I'm curios if anyone here has any ideas as to what might cause this issue, what possible fixes I could try and how I could go about investigating it.

### Additional info

> sudo lshw -c video

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:141 memory:a4000000-a4ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a5000000-a507ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:132 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

> free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       2,1Gi       3,1Gi       227Mi        10Gi        12Gi
Swap:         979Mi       165Mi       814Mi
```

> sudo dmidecode -s bios-version

```
GL704GW.302
```

> sudo dmidecode | grep -A3 '^System Information'

```
System Information
        Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
        Product Name: Strix GL704GW_GL704GW
        Version: 1.0
```

Comment: Please post output of `sudo lshw -c video`.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz added to the post, since it's too long to make a comment out of it

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`. Also, if you select the Intel video, does the same problem occur? What version nvidia driver?

Comment: @heynnema This information seem useless to show, as I said, memory usage is < 20% ( <3GB) when this happens. I can't "capture" `free -h` during a freeze since... my screen freezes, but logging memory usage & cpu usage doesn't seem to show anything interesting. There's no other "weird" things going on with memory, the kernel keeps most of it in buff/cache (all the one that's not available, leaving 0.5GB free) and swap usage is ~0 (28Mb out of 1GB). Would you mind telling me what exactly you want to garner from it ?

Comment: I asked three questions to begin to get a handle on what might be going on in your case. You didn't answer any of my questions. If you don't want to play, I can't help you.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry, I didn't notice the last question. What command do you want me to execute to give you the info about the gpu drivers ? I already posted some info about that in my post. As for selecting intel video, I don't know how to got about doing that.

Comment: `free -h`, select the video either in your BIOS, or I think there's a Nvidia utility app to do that, `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep -i ii`. Edit the outputs into your question, not into the comments, please. Also, give me the make/model # of your computer, and the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: @heynnema added the info in the original post, will try switching graphic drivers later, because I doubt the problem is related to that, I tried some GPU intensive operations and things went fine, on the other hand it seems I'm able to consistently replicate the freezes with writing/reading a lot of stuff to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer...

According to [this web page](https://www.asus.com/me-en/Laptops/ROG-Strix-SCAR-II/HelpDesk_Download/), you have an outdated BIOS.

**Note**: you must confirm that **your exact make/model** applies to this web page.

ASUS Strix GL704GW

---

- You have BIOS 302.
- Current is BIOS 308. "**Improve System Stability**".
- Download the update.
- **Note: Backup all of your important files first.**
- Apply the BIOS update.
- Retest your system.

---

Also, your swap is too small, and vm.swappiness will need to get tuned. We also need to check for /var/crash/*.crash logs, Nvidia driver issues, overclocked CPU/RAM, memtest86, and the SMART Data for your HDD. More on this later.

Comment: I set `swappiness` to 0, 1GB is the recommended swap by the Ubuntu install itself, but presumably I would notice a full swap (and before that) a full memory before this happens. Also, is there a possible explanation for why an outdated BIOS might cause this ? To my understanding the BIOS shouldn't matter much unless there's some specific hardware issue (e.g. CPU+RAM combination not working correctly at the default chosen frequency) that happens at boot time. Which in this case there doesn't seem to be, there's no major BIOS patches that would fix my issue.

Comment: @George It amazes me how folks come here for help, and then want to argue over the recommendations given to them, by some of us who have been here quite a lot longer. Your vm.swappiness is wrong, as is your swap size, as is your BIOS. Maybe it'll help, maybe it won't. But we have to start somewhere. And as you said "*After a day of debugging I'm close to giving up, since the issue is so hard to trace...*". I'm done.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and your intention to help. After investigating the issue further (see my update in the post as well), I believe the place where you are tracing the issue is wrong, and without a further argument as to why the issue could steam from there, I am not going to waste my time investigating. Again, I'm not saying I'm not thankful for wanting to help, I greately appreciate it, I just think you should spend your time trying to help some other users instead.